# Can't Send Email From Laravel Application : Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]

Tags: laravel, email, smtp, lamp, digital-ocean

I'm using digital ocean ubuntu machine & i want to send the forget password email

but every time i send the email this error shows up
using these settings :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=info@example.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

[image]

the strange thing is that it's working without any problems in my local environment using the same settings

by the way 
my info@example.com is a Gsuite account and it's working

i know some people would tell me to use

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
```

but everytime it sends the email it goes directly to the spam folder

i added the spf record

v=spf1 +a +ip4:xx.xxx.xx.xxx ~all

I Followed : 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-dkim-with-postfix-on-debian-wheezy

and added the record 
v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p='very long  key'

and still goes to the spam folder

i don't know what to do i want to use the google smtp or use sendmail or any other method just to send the email right into the normal inbox

please help ,thank you

Comment: Are you doing this locally, ie. sending from localhost?

Comment: @Dammeul Nope i'm doing this from a vps from digital ocean , anyway after a lot of digging and opening a ticket in digital ocean support center the solution was to change my droplet name to the same domain name to have a rdns but it took about a day to work , thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a lot of digging and opening a ticket in digital ocean support center

the solution was to change my droplet name to the same domain name to have a valid ptr record

it took about a day to work

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but I have no domain on my server. Only working with IP now... Did you know if I need an Domain?

Comment: @RamonSchmidt Hi, actually I don't know about that... maybe you can try to change the droplet name from "test" or "something" to the ip
my droplet name was website-test i changed it to website.com and after one day worked with no problems 
i hope it works for you